# Does a React Component require Render props?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react component....

```
const TestTemplate = ()=> (
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
)
```

I have been told this isn't a real component because it would need to accept render props but I am not using them. According to [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

> A component with a render prop takes a function that returns a React element and calls it instead of implementing its own render logic.

The with here is key to me it means a component may or may not have a render prop. Is this true or am I wrong? Does it need to be this to be valid?

```
const TestTemplate => (props)=>(
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
)
```

Comment: Updated to fix typos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that it *has* to accept props, but that it needs to be a function or a class that extends `React.Component`. The first example is just JSX, it is not a component because it is not a function that returns JSX.

It would be perfectly valid to change it to this:

```js
// Does not expect a `props` object, but is a functional component
const TestTemplate = () => (
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
)
```

The second example is also syntactically incorrect. The first arrow should just be an equal sign since its an assignment of a const.

You can read more about components [here in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

I think you're also misunderstanding what a "render prop" is. A render prop is a prop that contains JSX (or a function that returns JSX). It is not referring to the entire `props` object that can be passed into a component, but rather a *type* of prop.

For example, it may look something like this:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const renderProp = () => (<div>I'm from a render prop</div>);

  return <Child renderProp={renderProp} />
}

const Child = (props) => {
  return props.renderProp();
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This pattern can be used several different ways, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: I would remove the comment about the arrow since it was a typo and I updated but thank you.

Comment: Also a TLDR that a Component doesn't need props is enough. The simple jsx vs component thing is more of a side item because I could just wrap it in a function and it would be the same question

Comment: In the original question it was not a side thing, it was a critical difference between the two examples. Plus I think its important to understand that "props" and "render props" are not interchangeable terms.

Answer (score 0):

## Needs to be a function or a class

A real react component needs to be a function or a class.
You do not need to pass props for it to be a component.

The top example you gave is just a variable with some jsx inside, not a real component.